# Integer optimization with a variable size constraints

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

I have an integer program to solve of the following form:
\begin{align}
\min_{x\in\mathbb{Z}^n}& \quad f(x)\\
\text{s.t} &\quad g(x)\leq 0,
\end{align}
where $g$ is such that "$g(x)\in\mathbb{R}^{m(x)}$", where quotation marks indicate a moderate abuse of notation.

What kind of optimization problem is this? Are there any optimization solvers that accept a black-box function $g(x)$ of which elements should be non-positive but such that the codomain size is a variable?

Comment: What are $f$ and $g$ and $m$ for your problem?

Comment: $f$ is quadratic and $g$ is cubic. The idea is that with $g(x)\in\mathbb{R}^{m(x)}$ I could write a formulation where redundant constraints wouldn't be listed. Having given a further thought, a good solver should have a way of dealing with redundancy, so instead of some gimmicky formulation I should just formulate the complete problem and have the solver deal with the rest.